# Swapped image is overshadowed in firefox. Have to click twice to get rid of focus

Tags: jquery, firefox, focus, overlay

I have a jgal which works fine in other browsers except firefox.

http://www.beautiful-soul.co.uk/collections/ss13.php

The issue is that when you click on the thumbnail the main image changes but is overlayed with a focus that won't remove itself until you click twice on the image. I have tried altering the CSS and the JQuery but I cannot yet figure as to what is happening?

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I think it's a native Firefox focus/active issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't expect users to reverse-engineer your page. Please post a small working example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks... 1) Its not my code I was asked to see if I could fix it. 2) it was only a visual example to show you what it is doing in firefox... will post a scaled down version of that code as soon as i can... Its a simple firefox issue with a focus but even blur() or click() does not make it go away...not a coding problem I can see. Thanks